# Android have a Pre-Environment like Windows PE?

Tags: android

Is there are way to program a pre-environment for android to be able to fix it in case a virus gets in or the image gets corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reset to factory defaults"...?

---

EDIT:

Safe mode for android: http://www.shaneycrawford.com/2012/01/how-to-get-your-android-phone-out-of-safe-mode/

1. Turn the phone off.
2. Turn it back on and hold the “up” volume button.

Comment: You can do this from the recovery, power off the phone, then power+volumeUP (depends on the phone model etc).

Comment: I found out about safe mode - which is kind of like Windows PE mode